# RegEx for ranges

Tags: c#, regex, string, matchevaluator

I want to be able to use a RegEx to parse out ranges like a Windows Print dialog (such as 1-50,100-110,111,112). The following is my current code and I am not clear on how to parse for the additional commas and numbers. I can parse out the hyphen, but not sure how to do it for additional commas or hyphens

```
private void tboxRowNum_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex.Replace(tboxRowNum.Text, @"(?<first>\d+)-(?<last>\d+)",
    new MatchEvaluator(this.parseSpaceDefinition));

}

private string parseSpaceDefinition(Match m)
{
    int first = int.Parse(m.Groups["first"].Value);
    int last = int.Parse(m.Groups["last"].Value);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(first.ToString());

    for (int i = first + 1; i <= last; i++)
    {
        if (spaceItems == 0)
        {
            if (isNumeric(sb.ToString(),  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer))
            {
                startingSpace = Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString());
            }
        }

        sb.Append("," + i.ToString().Replace(" ", ""));

        spaceItems++;
        endingSpace = i;
    }

    tboxRowDesc.Text = sb.ToString();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Edit 1:** The modified code gets me what I want:

```
private void tboxRowNum_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] parts = tboxRowNum.Text.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        if (parts[i].IndexOf('-') >= 0)
        {
            Regex.Replace(parts[i], @"(?<first>\d+)-(?<last>\d+)",
            new MatchEvaluator(this.parseSpaceDefinition));
        }
        else
        {
            int number;
            if(!(int.TryParse(parts[i], out number))) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incomplete/Invalid formula", "Invalid Space Definition");
                tboxRowDesc.Text = "";
            }
            else 
            {
                tboxRowDesc.Text += "," + number;
                spaceItems++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know what kind of results do you expect? like this `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...50, 100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110, 111,112`?

Comment: Yes, 1-50 would be 1,2,3,4,5,6...50 and if it was 1-50,110,111,112 the result would be 1,2,3,4,5,6..50,110,111,112. I'd like to do it all in one regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] ranges = inputString.split(',');

foreach (string rangeCandidate in ranges) {
   // See if matches regex
}
```

Comment: Lol gotta love the easy ones :)

Answer (score 1):

Split it first on comma, and for each part check if it matches your regexp. If it does, do what you are already doing, otherwise just use int.Parse (or int.TryParse for robustness).